# MudBlazor - Searchable MudSelect

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm using MudBlazor, specifically `MudSelect`. I want to display the `Name` property, but save the `Id` property in the Value. The following is working.

```
<MudSelect T="int" Label="Assigned Group" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Required="true" RequiredError="An Assigned Group is required."  @bind-Value="newTask.GroupId" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Filled.Group">
    @foreach (var group in Groups)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="@group.Id">@group.Name</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>
```

But, as the number of options starts growing it makes sense to add a search field along the `Select List`. I don't know how to use that in `MudSelect`. And while using `MudAutocomplete`, which gives me a search function, I don't know how to associate the `Id` to the selected `Name`. And while, since my `Name`, is unique I can do some processing on the `submit` to get the `Id`, I want to prevent the extra processing

Comment: To my knowledge MudSelect does not support this. I looked for it, too, some time ago. I ended up using the `ToStringFunc` parameter of `MudAutocomplete`. Using that you can achieve everything you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71654461/12878692 this helped me it works well

Answer (score 4):

You can use CodeBeam.MudBlazor.Extensions package. It has MudSelectExtended and has built-in search support. It also has MudComboBox to similar search functions.

Can try here https://codebeam-mudextensions.pages.dev/mudselectextended

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, MudBlazor doesn't have dynamic data loading in MudSelect.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/2301), you can use Virtualization MudBlazor to achieve maximum performance for large number of items.

[Here](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkGcYbckrgEuRRnR) is an example of virtualization in MudSelect with large number of data.

It seems like that they're not working on dynamic data for MudSelect, don't wait for that (at least for next months).

more info: You can also use virtualization for tables, like [this](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#api).

Answer (score 1):

I changed to an autocomplete, showing the top ten by default, then as the user types, the list auto filters to the top 10 containing the text entered.

```
 <MudAutocomplete T="SM.Role"
     Value="_employee.Role"
     Label="Role"
     SearchFunc="@EmployeeViewModel.SearchRole"
     ResetValueOnEmptyText="@false"
     CoerceText="@false"
     DebounceInterval="500"
     CoerceValue="@false"
     ValueChanged="@OnRoleSelectionChanged"
     AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search"
     AdornmentColor="Color.Primary"
     ToStringFunc="@(e => e == null ? null : $"{e.Name}")" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a searchable `MudSelect` component in a `Blazor` application, you can create a custom component that inherits from `MudSelect` and overrides its `FocusAsync()` method. After that, you can add a search input within this custom component.

**Step 1: Create a CustomMudSelect Component**
First, create a new Blazor component and name it *CustomMudSelect*. In this component, inherit from *MudSelect* and override the *FocusAsync()* method.

**Step 2: Add a Search Input Inside CustomMudSelect**
include a search input in the component's markup. This will enable the user to filter items within the `MudSelect` component.

```
<i>
     
    public class CustomMudSelect<T>: MudSelect<T>
    {
      public override ValueTask FocusAsync()
      {
         return new ValueTask();
      }
    }

    <CustomMudSelect T="int" Label="Assigned Group" Variant="Variant.Outlined" 
    Required="true" RequiredError="An Assigned Group is required."@bind- 
    Value="newTask.GroupId" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Filled.Group">

        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." 
        @oninput="@((ChangeEventArgs e) => { searchText = 
        e.Value.ToString(); 
        StateHasChanged();})"/>
    
       @foreach (var group in Groups)
       {
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || 
                 group.Name.Contains(searchText, 
                 StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                )
                {
                   <MudSelectItem Value="@group.Id">@group.Name</MudSelectItem>
                }
           
       }
    </CustomMudSelect>


</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [MudBlazor.Extensions Nuget] (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MudBlazor.Extensions)

and then the best option in my case is to inherit MudExSelect like this

```cs
@using MudBlazor.Extensions.Options
@inherits MudExSelect<ProgramingSkill>
@Inherited()
@code {
    public override Func<ProgramingSkill, string> ToStringFunc { get; set; } = ItemNameRender;
    public override bool MultiSelection { get; set; } = true;
    
    protected RenderFragment Inherited() => builder => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    
    protected override Task<IList<ProgramingSkill>> GetAvailableItemsAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        // Load data from server for example
        return Task.FromResult<IList<ProgramingSkill>>(new List<ProgramingSkill>
        {
            new() { Name = "C#"},
            new() { Name = "C++"},
            new() { Name = "C"},
            new() { Name = "Objective-C"},
            new() { Name = "Swift"},
            new() { Name = "TypeScript"},
            new() { Name = "JavaScript"},
            new() { Name = "VisualBasic"},
            new() { Name = "Pascal"}
        });
    }
    private static string ItemNameRender(ProgramingSkill item) => $"{item.Name}";
}
```

A sample demo can be found [here](https://www.mudex.org/mud-ex-select)