# MudBlazor MudAutocomplete - how to show 'name's in the list, but bind an Id?

Tags: mudblazor

My model looks like this

```
public partial class EditModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
...

    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

My SearchItems method header looks like this

```
protected async Task<IEnumerable<ListItem>> SearchItems(string value)
```

which returns 'list' of these

```
public partial class ListItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get my MudAutocomplete to show the Name, yet return/bind the Id?

```
<MudAutocomplete T="ListItem" Label="Select item" @bind-Value="EditModel.Item"
    Clearable="true"
    MinCharacters="4" SearchFunc="@SearchItems"
    ToStringFunc="@(i => i==null ? null : $"{i.Id} [{i.Name}]")"
    SelectValueOnTab="true"/>
```

on the @bind-Value, Visual studio shows this error

**...cannot convert from 'string' to 'EditModel.Item'**

Comment: The problem is that you want to bind a `ListItem` object to a `EditModel.Item` object - they are different objects. 
What you need to do is to remove the `ListItem` object, you don't need it - just filter over a list of EditModels and then you will be properly binding EditModels to EditModels.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I solved it for now...

My SearchItems method now just returns a list of string

```
protected async Task<IEnumerable<string>> SearchItems(string value)
```

I've put this attribute in the MudAutocomplete

```
ToStringFunc="@(i => ItemDisplay(i))"
```

This is my ItemDisplay method

```
private string ItemDisplay(string itemId)
{
    var item = ListItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == itemId);

    return item == null ? "!Not Found!" : $"{item.Id} [{item.Name}]";
}
```

I've had to add this to my ComponentBase, to 'cache' all the ListItems for use in ItemDisplay() method:

```
public List<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; } = new();
```

In **OnInitializedAsync()**

```
ListItems = await MyService.GetItemsAsync();
```

I've set up my GetItemsAsync() to use IMemoryCache (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory), but I still don't like this approach.  I find it difficult to believe that this component does not support the feature.

Comment: it helped me. thanks for contrubuting mudblazor community.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the component is updated but I was able to achieve this by using the following approach which I think is good.

The model you want to use

```
record State(Guid Id, string Name);
```

The binding value

```
private State value1;
```

The search function returns `IEnumerable<State>`

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<State>> Filter(string value)
{
    // Filtering logic
}
```

Finally, I am using `ToStringFunc` to define how values are displayed in the drop-down list

```
<MudAutocomplete T="State" ToStringFunc="@(state => state.Name)" Label="US States" @bind-Value="value1" SearchFunc="@Filter" Variant="Variant.Outlined"/>
```